# Tensor has shape [None, None] when created with placeholders

Tags: python, tensorflow

The product of the two matrices below has a shape of [None, None] if the matrices are created with shapes given in placeholders, but have proper shape when created with ordinary literals:

With literals:

```
r1 = 3
r1f = 3.0
c2 = 2

#r1 = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
#r1f = tf.cast(r1, tf.float32)
#c2 = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)

m1 = tf.reshape(tf.range(r1f), (r1, 1))
m2 = tf.ones((1, c2))
t = tf.matmul(m1, m2)
s0 = tf.constant(t.shape[0].value)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(s0))
    #print(sess.run(s0, feed_dict={r1 : 3, c2 : 2}))


>>> 3
```

With placeholders:

```
#r1 = 3
#r1f = 3.0
#c2 = 2

r1 = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
r1f = tf.cast(r1, tf.float32)
c2 = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)

m1 = tf.reshape(tf.range(r1f), (r1, 1))
m2 = tf.ones((1, c2))
t = tf.matmul(m1, m2)
s0 = tf.constant(t.shape[0].value)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    #print(sess.run(s0))
    print(sess.run(s0, feed_dict={r1 : 3, c2 : 2}))


>>> ValueError: None values not supported.
```

I then ran the graph on `t.shape.as_list()` instead of `t.shape[0].value` with the error that the shape would be `[None, None]`.

I am running tensorflow 1.10.1.

My questions are: why do I get a shape of `[None, None]` in the second case and how can I obtain the proper shape?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with TensorFlow you should always keep in mind there are two phases:

- **Graph creation phase**. When you create placeholders, constants, variables and create some operations that will be applied to them.
- **Computation phase**. When you call `sess.run` and actual computations in graph take place.

In your code snippet when you do `t.shape[0].value` you are trying to access shape of tensor at *graph creation phase*. TensorFlow always tries to predict tensor shapes at graph creation stage whenever it possible. However, since you apply to your tensors reshape that uses placeholder value as new shape, the shape of the result can't be inferred until *computation phase*, since  placeholder value is unknown.

To mitigate this issue you have to treat shape of the tensor as another tensor instead of trying to access its numeric value at graph creation phase.

Please see the updated code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

r1 = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
r1f = tf.cast(r1, tf.float32)
c2 = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)

m1 = tf.reshape(tf.range(r1f), (r1, 1))
m2 = tf.ones((1, c2))
t = tf.matmul(m1, m2)
s0 = tf.shape(t)[0]

print(type(s0)) # <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'> # s0 is a Tensor!

with tf.Session() as sess:
    #print(sess.run(s0))
    print(sess.run(s0, feed_dict={r1 : 3, c2 : 2}))
```

> why does it work with literals but doesn't work with placeholders

Since the values of plain integer variables are know at graph creation stage, Tensorflow can predict the shape of reshape operation result at graph creation stage. So, the shape of the result can be accessed during graph creation.

Let's consider an example:

```
r1_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
r1f = tf.cast(r1_placeholder, tf.float32)
r1_int = 3

m1 = tf.reshape(tf.range(r1f), (r1_placeholder, 1))
print(m1.shape) # (?, 1) shape is unknown at graph creation stage, since r1_placeholder is a placeholder


m1 = tf.reshape(tf.range(r1f), (r1_int, 1))
print(m1.shape) # (3, 1) shape is known at graph creation stage, since r1_int is just a number
```

> So why does it work with tf.shape(t) and doesn't work with t.shape ?

`t.shape` gives you access to shape of the tensor inferred by TensorFlow at graph creation stage, which might be partially or completely unknown.

`tf.shape(t)` creates an operation in your graph that will compute the actual shape of the tensor at *computation stage*

Comment: My question was: why does it work with literals but doesn't work with placeholders. It works perfectly fine with literals which is why I don't think it has anything to do with t.shape[0] being "in the graph creation phase".

Comment: The values of literals in your first code snippet are known at graph creation phase. So tensorflow can infer shape of reshape operation result at graph creation stage.

Let's consider this example:

    m1 = tf.reshape(tf.range(r1f), (r1, 1))
    print(m1.shape) # (?, 1) shape is unknown at graph creation stage, since r1 as placeholder

    r1_int = 3
    m1 = tf.reshape(tf.range(r1f), (r1_int, 1))
    print(m1.shape) # (3, 1) shape is known at graph creatio stage, since r1_int is just a number

Comment: Indeed, this link https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#shape explains it all.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I obtain the proper shape?

The dynamic shape of the tensor `tf.matmul(m1, m2)` can be obtained like this. But values have to be fed to it.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(tf.shape(t))
    #print(sess.run(t, feed_dict={r1 : 3, c2 : 2}))
    print(sess.run(tf.shape(t), feed_dict={r1 : 3, c2 : 2}))
```

Comment: So why does it work with tf.shape(t) and doesn't work with t.shape ?

Answer (score 0):

The default shape of a placeholder tensor is `None` (unless you specify it). (See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder))

Thus, your shape is `(None, None)`, even though at runtime you are giving values for the tensors.